# "rpm -qa" not working ("Segmentation fault: 11")

Tags: macos, segmentation-fault, rpm

### Problem

- `rpm -qa` not working

```
$ rpm -qa
* Segmentation fault: 11
```

### State

1. Mac OS X 10.10.5
2. rpm version

```
$ sudo port search rpm

rpm @4.4.9_18 (sysutils, archivers)
    The RPM package management system.

rpm2html @1.9.6_1 (sysutils)
    Translates an RPM database and dependency information into HTML

rpm52 @5.2.1_9 (sysutils, archivers)
    Obsolete port, replaced by rpm54

rpm53 @5.3.11_4 (sysutils, archivers)
    Obsolete port, replaced by rpm54

rpm54 @5.4.15_1 (sysutils, archivers)
    The RPM package management system.

yum @3.2.29_1 (sysutils, archivers)
    Automatic updater and package installer/remover for RPM

Found 6 ports.
```

Comment: If you have the skills, you might consider running it thought the `lldb` debugger and getting a stack-trace from when it crashes. It may offer some hints as to why it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Either there is some bug in rpm (not very likely) or you are missing some dependency.

Try to run:

```
ldd  /usr/bin/rpm
```

And it will show you which libraries it is using. If there is something missing on right side of `=>`, then that is your problem.

Comment: Does MacPorts install to `/usr/bin`? I don't think it does, but I could be wrong. Also, `ldd` does not appear to be an OS X binary.